# Rustc compile without tmp dir

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-compiler-plugin

Is it possible to compile rust code without a tmp dir?

i.e.

```
rustc -C opt-level=3 -o "$DEST" "$@"
```

i'm getting the following error:

```
Compiling failed with exitcode 1, compiler output:
error: couldn't create a temp dir: No such file or directory (os error 2) at path "/tmp/rustcbQ2www"

error: aborting due to previous error
```

The reason tmp directory isn't available is this is adding rust support for DomJudge, and they run contestants codes in a chroot without tmp, or with potentially a different tmp folder name.

failing that, is there a way to change the tmp dir that rustc uses? e.g. an environment variable e.g. >>TMPDIR=/my_tmp_tmp

Comment: check this [comment on github](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/4350#issuecomment-340215811) : setting `$TMPDIR` should do the trick

Comment: cool, seems to work, now just need to find a directory i have permission to use. I wonder if i can just set $TMPDIR to .

Comment: Maybe just create one? `mkdir tmp; export TMPDIR=$PWD/tmp`

Answer (score -1):

You can see [Adding a new language](https://github.com/DOMjudge/domjudge/wiki/Adding-a-new-language) which goes into the question explicitly: set `CREATE_WRITABLE_TEMP_DIR` in the judgehost config.